# What dir should I deploy Rails apps into?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, deployment, ruby-on-rails, redhat

What would be a reasonable and logical directory into which to deploy my production Rails apps on a Linux system?

Some candidates...

```
/var/rails  <= There's a /var/www so this would be consistent with that 
               pattern. But I.T. guys have complained about stuff in /var 
               before.

/home/my_home_dir/rails  <= OK, not /var, but I'm not the only developer. 
                            Seems like it really ought to be a systemwide
                            location.

/home/rails  <= I don't know. That just seems weird.

/rails  <= Seems even weirder.
```

What is the least astonishing, most normal thing to do here?

(Background info -- a Rails app is a bunch of server side code written in Ruby along with a `public` dir containing JavaScript, CSS, and maybe a little HTML. The `public` dir is mapped to an Apache vhost. Apache handles the Ruby code through a module called Passenger or `mod_rails`.)

---

Thanks for the help, all. I think I'm going to go with `/opt/deployed_rails_apps`. (I like long, expository directory names, and tab completion.) `/var/...` is also a good place, but I've gotten stern grumbling from I.T. when I tried to deploy stuff there. If it were my own machine I might go with `/var` or `/srv`.

Comment: You may want to see this other related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/29129/where-to-place-web-content-for-multiple-domains-on-a-rhel-based-server/29134#29134

Comment: a side question but still related i was working on a rails project contained in the ~/Documents/quotes (directory) and after deploying it, found much to my surprise some 6 months later, that the identical folder structure is also in /var/www/html/quotes - when deploying does rails copy it to the var folder? I have no idea how it all got there from the other directory. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think **/opt** would be the place for an **application** like this.  I agree with following the FHS as suggested by chmeee, but I don't agree that a Rails app is a service per se.

Comment: It's difficult to tell, actually the rails software is isntalled in the system somewhere (as a gem or package), what he wants to place is the directory structure for the 'service', the actual application that uses rails to serve something.

Comment: I recognized he's talking about an app he's created (hence, "a Rails app"), rather than Rails itself.  Either way, /srv seems wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) and place it in

```
/srv : Data for services provided by this system
```

**EDIT:**

I wouldn't place it in `/opt`:

```
/opt : Add-on application software packages
```

It's purpose says:

> /opt is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.
>
> A package to be installed in /opt must locate its static files in a separate /opt/ or /opt/ directory tree, where  is a name that describes the software package and  is the provider's LANANA registered name.

I don't think a developed application is a 'software package'.

The rationale for `/srv` is

> This main purpose of specifying this is so that users may find the location of the data files for particular service, and so that services which require a single tree for readonly data, writable data and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed.

I understand that a rails app is a cgi script and should be placed in `/srv`.

Comment: I wouldn't be too fanatical about what the FHS says. The most important thing is to keep your custom packages away from the operating system files. And the best places for that are "/usr/local" and "/opt".

Comment: I'm not fanatical, but I like their filesystem organization. In any case I agree that /usr/local and /opt are good for software packages, but I don't think that a rails app is a software package

Comment: Based on what the FHS says, `/srv` seems like the most fitting directory to me. I'm using `/srv/rails/application_name`.

Answer (score 7):

On CentOS Linux distributions (and subsequently RedHat), when you install the httpd package (for Apache 2), it creates `/var/www`, and expects that your vhosts point to your web content here. The default vhost is typically dumped in `/var/www/htdocs`, and subsequent sites/apps should be put in `/var/www/sitename`.

The actual location shouldn't matter much, but it's common to see `/opt/www/sitename`, `/var/www/sitename`, or simply `/opt/www` or `/var/www`.

You've already stated a few of the reasons why some of the other locations (like `/home`) are not really suited for this.

Personally, I prefer `/var/www/sitename` since it's friendly to Apache and Rails, and is system-wide.

Comment: Web apps should go in /var/www, especially if they are served through something like a proper webserver like Apache of Lighttpd. The more so, since SELinux policies will be properly applied to a Rails app in /var/www and not in /opt.

Answer (score 0):

In debian/ubuntu based system such applications are usually installed in /usr/share folder (i.e. /usr/share/ruby), since they are non-compiled files (which would go into /usr/lib). Since your application is not a standard application you would probably put it in /usr/local/share preventing it there being overwritten by any system updates.

/opt is certainly also a possibility here.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put them in /opt/app_name.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my deploys in

/home/www.example.com/application

The arguments:

Home will contain all the moving parts of a single website.
If I have more websites I will know where to find them.